# Find the maximum column-sum with hundreds of variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with header like this -

> id | group | col1 | col2 |....| col100

For each group, I would like to find out the top 5 column header and column sum.

So I am anticipating

> Group | Top1 ColName | Top1 ColSum | Top2 ColName| Top2 ColSum |...

I have written a connector in R and use R to do that. Just curious,
1) Is it possible to do that directly in SQL?
2) Is it possible to do an automatic `group by...Sum` statement so that I don't have to type in each the column name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get close to this with UNPIVOT...

For example (elided):

```
SELECT group, colName, colValue
FROM t
UNPIVOT
(
   colValue for colName IN (col1, col2, col3...)
) up
```

Now you can use that as follows:

```
WITH Unpivoted AS
(
    SELECT group, colName, colValue
    FROM t
    UNPIVOT
    (
       colValue for colName IN (col1, col2, col3...)
    ) up
)

, GroupColumnSums AS
(
    SELECT group, colName, SUM(colValue) AS colSum
    FROM Unpivoted
    GROUP BY group, colName
)

, RankedColumnSums AS
(
    SELECT group, colName, colSum, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY group, colName ORDER BY colSum DESC) AS sumRank
    FROM GroupColumnSums
)

SELECT group, colName, colSum, sumRank
FROM RankedColumnSums
WHERE sumRank <= 5
```

However, I don't think you will be able to easily repivot it such that you can do {Top1ColName, Top1ColSum}, {Top2ColName, Top2ColSum}

SQL can PIVOT, however it can only do so on one column.  So what we'd have to do is "combine" colName and colSum into one (e.g. colName + '|' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), colSum), pivot on that, and then "unpack" the result back into the separate columns for 'name' and 'sum'.

Comment: Can't you just do `SELECT group, MAX(CASE WHEN sumRank = 1 THEN ColName ELSE '' END) AS Top1ColName, MAX(CASE WHEN sumRank = 1 THEN colSum ELSE 0 END) AS Top1ColSum ...`

Comment: I think you're right, that would do it (I'd use SUM instead of MAX for the ColSum though, otherwise it won't work with negative values)

Comment: @MarkSowul: Or you could still use MAX but replace `ELSE 0` with `ELSE NULL` (or just omit the ELSE clause all together).

Comment: That's hackish.  It's not immediately obvious that `NULL` is considered the minimum, and comparing `NULL` with values is fairly unnatural, as it doesn't behave like other comparisons with `NULL` (for example WHERE `5 < NULL` gives you `NULL`)